# Generic types in static method

Tags: java, class, generics, methods, static

I'm having a problem with Generic Types in static method. I have this code:

```
public class BST<E extends Comparable<E>> {

    public static class Node<T> {
        private T value;
        private Node<E> left, right, parent;

        private Node(T v) {
            value = v;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return value.toString();
        }
    }
....
}
```

then i wanna use Node  in this static method:

```
public static <E> boolean equalTrees(Node<E> r1, Node<E> r2)
```

but at Node is giving me this error:

The member type BST.Node must be qualified with a parameterized type, since it is not static

I've searched and can't find the answer to that.

Comment: Where is the `equalTrees` method? is it inside the `BST` class or inside the `Node` class?

Comment: Please retag with the appropriate language (Java I presume).

Comment: I've encountered the problem and I've solved it not declaring Node as as inner class, but creating a new file containing only the Node class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class BST<E extends Comparable<E>> {

    public static <E> boolean equalTrees(Node<E> r1, Node<E> r2) {
        return false;
    }

    public static class Node<E> {
        private E value;
        private Node<E> left, right, parent;
    }

}
```

Comment: Then i get this error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type E

Comment: There's something missing in your question, you should post more of your code because as I mentioned, the above works for me

Comment: Edited with the entire Node class

Comment: I edited my answer, please check if the above code works for you